# Mobile browsers aren't tracked by Ruby CGI script

Tags: ruby, apache, mobile, browser, cgi

I placed an image link on my blog, which in fact refers to a Ruby CGI script on my Apache webserver. The CGI script provides the image data for the browsers by simply writing its content to the STDOUT, and then logs the visitors data, taken from the appropriate environment variables, tries to identify the country information through ipinfo.io, etc. Everything is going fine, however mobile browsers aren't tracked. They are completely missing from the log. What can I do to include them into my log file?

My Ruby CGI script looks like follow: https://gist.github.com/Konstantinusz/e53b11a915bae54b67a4

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turned out that my image was in png format, but I treated it as a jpg image. Desktop browsers worked with it, but mobile browsers not.